# How can I rotate an object based on an angle?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working in Unity3D and I was wondering how I would rotate a cube based on the angle between the cube and the mouse position. With that I don't mean the mouse position in world space but in pixels.

Comment: Stackoverflow does not provide answers for generic questions! you will get down voted! You'd better research/try and then ask a question with what you have tried and what is going wrong!
PS: this is do-able in unity3d! ;)

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more specific about what my question actually was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some pages that'll lead you to your answer:

[`Input.mousePosition`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) This also includes an example of how to turn screen coordinates into a ray in world coordinates. If you know how far away from the camera you want your point, check out [ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) for a point instead of a ray.

[`transform.Rotate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) To perform a rotation.

The rest of your question is kinda vague--rotating "based on" the angle between cube and mouse position could mean a lot of things. You shouldn't need much more information than this though!